# Remove first occurence of match in regex golang

Tags: regex, string, go

I have the following string:

```js
new k8s.KubeRoleBinding(this, "argocd-application-controller", {
    kind: "RoleBinding",
    metadata: {
        labels: {
            "app.kubernetes.io/component": "application-controller",
            "app.kubernetes.io/name": "argocd-application-controller",
            "app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "argocd",
        },
        name: "argocd-application-controller",
    },
    roleRef: {
        apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
        kind: "Role",
        name: "argocd-application-controller",
    },
    subjects: [{
        kind: "ServiceAccount",
        name: "argocd-application-controller",
    }],
});
```

Id like to remove the line which has the first occurence of `kind:`

I tried the following so far, but it removes all occurrences.

```golang
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?m)[\r\n]+^.*kind.*$")
    res := re.ReplaceAllString(str, "$1")
```

Playground link with code : https://play.golang.org/p/SMiyTJvKNVF

Wanted string :

```
new k8s.KubeRoleBinding(this, "argocd-application-controller", {
    metadata: {
        labels: {
            "app.kubernetes.io/component": "application-controller",
            "app.kubernetes.io/name": "argocd-application-controller",
            "app.kubernetes.io/part-of": "argocd",
        },
        name: "argocd-application-controller",
    },
    roleRef: {
        apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
        kind: "Role",
        name: "argocd-application-controller",
    },
    subjects: [{
        kind: "ServiceAccount",
        name: "argocd-application-controller",
    }],
});
```

Comment: Because the regexp does not have submatch, $1 evaluates to the empty string.  Is it your intent to delete the match or did you intend to use [ReplaceAllLiteralString](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.ReplaceAllLiteralString) instead of ReplaceAllString?

Comment: @TaylorRex, I updated my question to add my desired value.
Id like to delete the entire line that contains the first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the location of the first match. Use string slice operations to delete the match.

```
loc := re.FindStringIndex(str)
res := str
if loc != nil {
    res = str[:loc[0]] + str[loc[1]:]
}
```

[Run the example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QDA5FJa2hLI).